# What is the difference between 每天(都) and 天天?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

As far as I can find, 每天 is slightly more formal?

Comment: Check the explanations on this website:
https://www.chinlingo.com/articles/601522/

Answer (score 8):

Yes, 每天 is slightly more formal.

And sometimes, 天天 can be used to **emphasize** "every day is too often": 我每天 (it's OK) 去工作，你却**天天** (too often) 逃课！

Comment: Yes, we sometimes unconsciously use 天天 to show annoyance, spoken slightly louder.

Comment: What do you think of 好好学习，天天向上？

Comment: @埃博拉酱 Good question. It means very often and good.

Comment: I think "天天" have special rhythm so it uses more likely to be used to express emotion. No matter good or bad.

Answer (score 5):

The latter is used solely in spoken Chinese, while the former may be used in writing.

e.g.

我每天都学习汉语。
is equivalent to
我天天学习汉语

Speaking the former one sounds (sometimes) a little weird, but not much. While writing the latter one is not usually seen outside of quoting others.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, there is no difference. 天天 emphasizes more and can highlight the object's persistence in doing something.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing, but the former is often used in writing